# Do I gain life if a creature I control with lifelink deals damage to another creature or player?

Tags: magic-the-gathering

I control [Stonehorn Chanter](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Stonehorn%20Chanter), which has lifelink.

If Stonehorn Chanter deals damage to an opposing player, do I gain life?

If Stonehorn Chanter deals damage to an opposing creature, do I gain life?

Comment: You can use `[mtg:Card Name]` to tag cards.

Comment: @Rainbolt Is that better that the linking system I have used?
And how does that "tagging" work?

Comment: That depends on what you mean by "better". If Wizards of the Coast changed the URL for the Gatherer, your link would be broken until manually fixed. Auto card links are fixed  automatically as soon as the auto card feature is updated. Auto card provides consistency across our site by having all cards link to the same database. It's also easier to type. On the other hand, cards with apostrophes and cards whose names are contained in another card's name don't work (like Sun Titan and Sundering Titan). *"Tagging"* here means *"generate a link"*.

Comment: Also, it's easier :) Unfortunately, because of a bug in Gatherer, `[mtg:...]` doesn't work if the card name as an apostrophe ("`'`").

Comment: @Rainbolt Do I have a choice to decide between these options, or do you decide it for me?

Comment: @Damaskox You have a choice.

Comment: Why do you think you wouldn't gain the life? It says so right in the reminder text. I think a short sentence explaining the source of your doubts would improve the question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When a creature with lifelink deals damage to anything (creature, planeswalker, or player) with any cause (spell, ability or combat), you gain that much life. That means that yes, dealing damage to a blocking creature in combat makes you gain life from lifelink. Rule [702.15b](http://mtgsalvation.gamepedia.com/Lifelink) says

> Damage dealt by a source with lifelink causes that source’s controller, or its owner if it has no controller, to gain that much life (in addition to any other results that damage causes). See rule 119.3.